# function any is not consistent when applied on columns or the whole dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a dataframe that might contain NaN values.

```
array = np.empty((4,5))
array[:] = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(array)
df.iloc[1,3] = np.NaN

df.isna().apply(lambda x: any(x), axis = 0)
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

When I run:

```
any(df.isna())
```

It returns:

```
True
```

If there are no NaNs:

```
array = np.empty((4,5))
array[:] = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(array)
#df.iloc[1,3] = np.NaN

df.isna().apply(lambda x: any(x), axis = 0)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

However when I run:

```
any(df.isna())
```

It returns:

```
True
```

Why this is the case? Do I have any misunderstanding of the function any()?

Comment: The lambda wrapper would be unnecessary: `df.isna().apply(any, axis = 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why this is the case? Do I have any misunderstanding of the function any()?

When you loop over a DataFrame you are actually iterating over its column labels, not its rows or values as you might think. More precisely, the for loop calls `Dataframe.__iter__` which returns an iterator over the column labels of the DataFrame.
For instance, in the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
for x in df:
    print(x)

# Output:
#
# a
# b
# c
```

`x` holds the name of each `df` column. You can also see what is the output of `list(df)`.

This means that when you do `any(df.isna())`, under the hood `any` is actually iterating over the column labels of `df` and checking their truthiness. If at least one is truthy it returns `True`.

In both of your examples the column labels are numbers `list(df.isna()) = list(df.columns) = [0, 1, 2, 3]`, from which only 0 is a Falsy value. Therefore, in both cases `any(df.isna()) = True`.

---

**Solution**

The solution is to use `DataFrame.any` with `axis=None` instead of using the built-in `any` function.

```
df.isna().any(axis=None)
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect! Thank you!